# Outlook rule to move a different email than the one that triggered the rule

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, vba, office365

I get a series of emails (separate, not in the same conversation) for approvals.  The first email will have a subject line "ACTION REQUIRED: [XYZ] approval request."  If another user approves it before me, I get a second email with a subject line "Approval for [XYZ] has been user approved."  I would like to leave the first email in my inbox until the second email is received.  If I get the second email, I would like a rule to move both emails with a matching [XYZ] number to a different folder.  Is this possible?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think so because native Outlook rules don't have the ability to dynamically parse subject lines.  I think you would need a custom add-in or marcro to provide this functionality.

Comment: This calls for VBA.

Comment: Not possible using the built-in rules within Outlook. On the one hand, it's not feasible to move mails based on a dynamic matching value. On the other hand, a rule cannot get triggered when the second mail is received.

Comment: I would be willing to run a VBA macro but I'm not skilled enough to write one from scratch.  Any ideas what that would look like?

Comment: Here's a thread discussing similar topic for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57266103/match-two-emails-same-number-with-vba-and-regex-then-move-both-mails

You can add the tag "vba" so that vba experts could also see your post.

Comment: That's very helpful, thank you!  I'll see what I can do with this.

Comment: My pleasure : )